# How to use directory parameter with find command in Linux(Fedora- 20)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

I have this following find command in linux terminal

```
find $2 -maxdepth 1 -iname "*$1*"
```

This command is not returning to me anything..

second parameter is for directory and the first one is filename pattern

It is working when i use this command like

```
find /home/user/ -maxdepth 1 -iname "*de*"
```

in terminal without parameter it is returning Desktop.With parameters it is not working.

Why this is happen and what is the solve of this problem?

Also i want to truncate the beginning of the output.I only want the filenames, not the path and filename.

Edit:

I get the parameters when executing program.
Like: ./Program.sh de /home/user

with this calling, program is not executed well. becaue nothing happens in terminal.
In my program only the same command in it, nothing else

Thanks for help..

Comment: Is your `find` command in a script?

Comment: from where you getting $2 value??

Comment: The first version should return at least "." if nothing else. Could you possibly paste the actual directory contents and screen output?

Comment: Your one-line command works fine in my system.  To truncate the folder names, try to pipe your results to  `xargs -i basename {}`, i.e. `{Your command} | xargs -i basename {}`

Comment: Since your one-line command works fine in my system, I will just do a wild guess and give some suggestions on how to make it work:  1. change your first line of the script from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`, if it is not yet so.   2. update your "find" utility program.  (What is your find utility program version? Mine is GNU findutils 4.5.11.)

Comment: It might be that if you don't encapsulate $2 in "" it might be escaping it.

Comment: Please, run your script by means of ***sh -x*** to display the real  ***find*** command executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with updating the find utility program.

Thanks for your help and advises.